# HTML search box with modifiable hyperlink

Tags: html, forms

I'm wondering is it possible to create an HTML search box with a hyperlink modifiable by the input of the user?  For example

```
<form action="http://websitename.com/search=***the user's input text***">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button type="submit">Search This Website</button>
</form>
```

If this is possible, is the above code an accurate way of executing such a feature.  I know I'll need some sort of basic JavaScript, but what might that look like, and do I need to add/change anything to the html above?  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
This is the exact code:

```
<form class="octopart-search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Octopart.." name="search" onchange="this.form.action='http://octopart.com/search?q='+this.value;return true;">
    <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

This is the user's entry: 0201X103K250SNT

The resulting URL looks like this: http://octopart.com/search?search=0201X103K250SNT

When it **SHOULD** look like this: http://octopart.com/search?q=0201X103K250SNT

Somehow, the name="search" is being inserted where the 'q' should be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want browser recognize this action like a search engine, then use the `type="search"` as in:

```html
<form action="http://websitename.com/search">
        <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
        <button type="submit">Search This Website</button>
</form>

<!-- When a user clicks submit, the link will look like 
http://websitename.com/search?q=user_input -->
```

Comment: best of luck! @Jonny1998

Answer (score 1):

If, as in most cases, you need the search term be transmitted as an HTTP parameter, you can do it straightforward, without any scripting:

```
<form action="http://websitename.com/search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="q">
    <button type="submit">Search This Website</button>
</form>
```

Behaviour: Whenever the user press the submit button, the browser will do an hyperjump to URL=`http://websitename.com?search=<user data>`.

Instead, if you need the search term be *part* of the URI, you'll need some scripting:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" onchange="this.form.action='http://websitename.com/search/'+this.value;return true;">
    <button type="submit">Search This Website</button>
</form>
```

Behaviour: Whenever the user press the submit button, the browser will do an hyperjump to URL=`http://websitename.com/search/<user data>`.

### Update

To obtain a URL like this `http://octopart.com/search?q=<text>` I strongly recommend you the first option.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  I'm getting a slightly unanticipated result from the code however, the URL that is processed is not that one that is submitted (I think).  I'm entering a specific piece of the HTTP parameter with the text field and your code and the once the hyperjump is complete, the URL does not reflect the text field input.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the exact value you entered into the text input? Does it contain blanks or special characters?

Comment: After debugging for a while, I've learned this is a redirect error because the javascript for some reason inserts an extra term into the URL when it executes and the website obviously has no DOM connected with that url.  See my EDIT on my main post, maybe you can shed some light on this...

Comment: OK. See my edit. I've updated the 1st option to match your requirements.